# remote chunking with the control on reader in spring batch

Tags: spring, multiprocessing, spring-batch, processors

I have to use spring batch to read the file and process the contents in batches. I thought of using remote chunking, but it wont meet my actual requirement. I just mentioned my requirement below;

```
                      ____Item Processor1---->
                     |                       |
   Item Reader --->Item --Item Processor2----> ---ItemWriter
                     |                       |
                     | -- Item Processor n--->
```

Say for example, if my commit count is 20, I wanted the ItemReader to read 20 items and should distribute to the concurrent processors and the same should commit by the ItemWriter, and the next 20 records should read only after the successful completion of first chunk of 20.

Can anybody please help me to resolve the requirement please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered using a partitioner that spreads the workload on tasklets that execute in parallel? (http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/scalability.html section 7.4)

Comment: Have you looked at the `AsyncItemProcessor` and `AsyncItemWriter`?

Comment: @Michael and aksamit, thanks for the response..I tried with AsyncItemProcessor and AsyncItemWriter and it is working as expected..! testing with different scenario's..thanks again :)